# AngularJS ng-change on select with custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, dom-events

In my application I have a custom directive with select tag.

```
<div class="row pv10" ng-if="item.visible">
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-danger"><span ng-if="item.label_visible"> {{item.label}}</span></div>
     <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-1">
            <select ng-options="oneItem for oneItem in item.options" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="changeEvent()">
                {{selectedItem | json}}
            </select>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to perform an  action on every change event. I thought of using ng-change, which btw. worked just fine with radioBtn/checkBox. I tried two approaches here.

Firstly I tried to pass "changeEvent" function to the directive's isolated scope.

```
<custom-select item='item' change-event="change()" ng-if="item.component == 'select'" />
```

changeEvent() function exists in current controller (attached to the view holding custom-select)

```
scope: {
        item: "=",
        changeEvent: "&"
    }
```

Sadly expression does not evaluate on change.
Secondly I tried to attach the function directly to directive

```
link: function ($scope, elems, attrs) {
        $scope.changeEvent = function () {
            alert("Change Event!");
        }
    }
```

but it didn't work either.

I read somewhere  that ng-change even used within a custom directive operates on a controllers scope, not isolated scope of directive. However am not quite sure about that.
I'd really appreciate your help.

### EDIT!

This is a JSFiddle to the directive I use. If I should provide more details, just let me know, this is the first time I've ever used jsfiddle.

This is how the directive is invoked:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in jsonData">
  <div class="col-xs-12">   
    <cbp-select item='item' change="change()" ng-if="item.component == 'select'" />
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/60nsfg0L/

### EDIT2

When I have uploaded my solution to our local server it started to work properly.(Yes, I cleaned browser's cash, and my locals wamp/iss cache too).
But now I have a different problem.
I have a form built from different directives(like the one above), all have ng-click/change/blur. Everything seems to work fine until I change one of the options in my "select" directive. After selecting one of the values, ng-change expression is triggered (for not its just a simple alert) and from that moment onwards am not able to focus on any other elements. Weirdly enough, if I cause ng-change to trigger on any other element be it radiobtn or checkbox this problem does not occur.

Comment: Could you paste whole directive code?

Comment: @BroiSatse, question has been updated.

Comment: In your first try, did you try change-event="change" instead of change-event="change()" ? The brackets fire the function instead of returning it.

Comment: Sadly, it didn't help.

Comment: could you toss this in a fiddle or something?

Comment: See example here - http://jsfiddle.net/RmDuw/363/

Comment: @ajmajmajma, I have updated my question :)